# How to avoid resubmitt form when user refresh page in jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to prevent resubmit data to database when refresh the page. How to apply Post redirect get method in jsp. I refer lots of web sites but I cant find how to do that in jsp. please help me

Comment: After you handle a POST request redirect to the next resource, here is an [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jsp/send-redirect-in-jsp-page/). Besides of that, jsp shoul be used only for view, you should implement redirection in a servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to design your application according to [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Please check [this](http://www.javacodebook.com/2013/08/20/post-redirect-get-pattern-in-spring-mvc/) article for Spring MVC example